# Groovy Installation - "Failed to process package 'tf2_ros'" in "catkin_make_isolated" - MacBook OSX

Tags: ros, tf2-ros, ros-groovy, macbook

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After resolving the dependencies in the installation of groovy on a MacBook Pro with OS 10.8.3, I input the command

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install
```

This command executes several installations, but fails when trying to trying to process the "tf2_ros" package. The first error that I see is the "undefined symbols for architecture x86_64":

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'tf2_ros'
==> Building with env: '/Users/jjameson/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/Users/jjameson/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/tf2_ros'
==> make -j4 -l4 in '/Users/jjameson/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/tf2_ros'
Linking CXX shared library /Users/jjameson/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/tf2_ros/lib/libtf2_ros.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

This is the last few lines before the installation exits.

```
typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, actionlib::SimpleActionClient<tf2_msgs::LookupTransformAction_<std::allocator<void> > > >, boost::_bi::value<actionlib::SimpleActionClient<tf2_msgs::LookupTransformAction_<std::allocator<void>> >*> > > > in buffer_client.cpp.o
  "vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base", referenced from:
     boost::detail::thread_data_base::thread_data_base() in transform_listener.cpp.o
     boost::detail::thread_data_base::thread_data_base() in buffer_client.cpp.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [/Users/jjameson/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/tf2_ros/lib/libtf2_ros.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/tf2_ros.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 658, in build_workspace_isolated
    number=index + 1, of=len(ordered_packages)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 443, in build_package
    install, jobs, force_cmake, quiet, last_env, cmake_args, make_args
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 297, in build_catkin_package
    run_command(make_cmd, build_dir, quiet)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 186, in run_command
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, ' '.join(cmd))
CalledProcessError: Command '/Users/jjameson/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4' returned non-zero exit status 2
<== Failed to process package 'tf2_ros': 
  Command '/Users/jjameson/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> /Users/jjameson/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4

Command failed, exiting.
```

So I then input the command to reproduce the error

```
/Users/jjameson/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4
```

And the output for this command is

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I'm honestly getting a little lost in the code here and not really sure where to go. Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64175/groovy-installation---%22failed-to-process-package-%27tf2_ros%27%22-in-%22catkin_make_isolated%22---macbook-osx/) by [jjameson18](https://answers.ros.org/users/5004/jjameson18/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Check out this page.](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source)

(Not sure if this is what you need)

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2013-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jjameson18](https://answers.ros.org/users/5004/jjameson18/) on 2013-06-03**:
Yes, the command that is initially used, "./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install", is the first in section 2.1.3. My installation is getting held up when the "tf2_ros" package is being processed during this command.

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-06-03**:
I was actually referring to this part: http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source#tf2_ros_fails_to_build

**Comment by [jjameson18](https://answers.ros.org/users/5004/jjameson18/) on 2013-06-03**:
Haha, well I guess the answer was right in front of my face... Thanks for the help.

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-06-04**:
No problem :)